Vue, vite, can’t establish a connection to the server at wss, WebSocket connection to wss failed, 502 bad gateful, SSL
I have a Vue frontend that I deploy using a Docker container. My configuration looks like this:
vite.config.js:
...
plugins: [vue()],

server: {
  port: 8080,
 
  host: '0.0.0.0',

  https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./fullchain.pem'),
  }
}
...

I'm using docker, so I run
docker compose up

I checked the container filesystem using
sudo docker exec -it containername sh

and files are there:
/app
  privkey.pem
  fullchain.pem
  package.json
  vite.config.js
  ...

However when I go to the websitename.xyz I get 502 Bad Gateway error.
FIX 1:
If I comment out the https lines in vite.config.js, the website loads fine, but has
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://websitename.xyz/.
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:8080/.

[vite] failed to connect to websocket.
your current setup:
  (browser) websitename.xyz/ <--[HTTP]--> localhost:8080/ (server)
  (browser) websitename.xyz:/ <--[WebSocket (failing)]--> localhost:8080/ (server)

errors.
FIX 2:
I think it could something to do with Vue's hot reload.
When I do
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]

in Dockerfile, in place of
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

the error disappears. My understanding is that hot reload doesn't work in that case.

That you specifically mention firefox suggests that the problem doesn't exist in other browsers (chrome). Is that so?

@EstusFlask No, it happens in other browsers too. WebSocket connection to 'wss://websitename.xyz/' failed: 

You may want to clarify in the question that this isn't an issue with firefox per se
